# Form Submit is not working on angular even when button is inside a form

Tags: angular

I cannot hit my action when I hit the button submmit inside my Form. But if I just use the `(click)="onSubmit()"`, I hit the action. Please see my code below:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm(): void{
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      userName: [null, Validators.required],
      password: [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit(values: any): void{
    debugger;
    console.log(values);
  }
}

 <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
              <div class="row"><!--Username-->
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-3">

                  <div class="formgroup">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Uesrname"
                      formControlName="userName">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div> <!--Username-->
              <div class="mt-2 row"><!--Password-->
              <div class="col-md-6 offset-3">
                <div class="formgroup">
                  <label>Password</label>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    formControlName="password">
                </div>
              </div>
              </div><!--Password-->
              <div class="mt-2 row"><!--Login Button-->
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-3">
                  <div class="button-container pull-right">
                    <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-fill btn-danger">Login</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div><!--Login Button-->
            </form>
```

As you can see, my button type submit is inside my form. Can you please tell me what's going on? Thank you.

Comment: Did you check console for error? Same code working fine.

Comment: Using your exact code, it submits: [stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tamund?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: @Sanjay There is no error in my console..

Comment: @PoulKruijt, Hmmmm. it's weird.... I don't know what's going on. I may end up using the normal button and just get the values from the form.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 with the current code you've provided, there is no bug. So I guess you do not have that exact code in your app :)

Comment: @PoulKruijt, I copy pasted my whole html code in you stack and it worked there, I do not know why it's mot working on mine.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 perhaps it's an angular version difference/bug

Comment: Thank you for all your input. It took me a while only to find out that my ReactiveForms Module was in a different module. I am sorry to have wasted your time on my foolishness.

Comment: I think that is `(submit)` NOT (ngSubmit)